# Using VBA in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

We have been using VBA code for years with Excel 2003.  I have about 70 files that I pull information from and compile it into one spreadsheet.  This time, it only recognizes 3 of the 70.  I do not get any errors.  I noticed that all 3 recognized are the old version ".xls." and all not being recognized are the ".xlsx".  The portion of the code that I think is causing the problem is below.  Can anyone help?

```
Public currApp As String
Public i As String
Public recordC As String
Public excelI As Integer
Public intFileHandle As Integer
Public strRETP As String
Public errFile As String

Public Function loopFiles(ByVal sFolder As String, ByVal noI As Integer)

 'This function will loop through all files in the selected folder
 'to make sure that they are all of excel type

Dim FOLDER, files, file, FSO As Object

excelI = noI
'MsgBox excelI
i = 0

'Dim writeFile As Object
'writeFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("D:\Test\test.txt", "sdgdfgds", False)

Dim cnn As Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

currApp = ActiveWorkbook.path
errFile = currApp & "\errorFile.txt"

If emptyFile.FileExists(errFile) Then
    Kill errFile
Else
    'Do Nothing
End If


'cnn.Open "DSN=AUTOLIV"
'cnn.Open "D:\Work\Projects\Autoliv\Tax workshop\Tax Schedules\sox_questionnaire.mdb"
cnn.Open ("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & currApp & "\tax_questionnaire.mdb")

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 'Upon each found excel file it will make a call to saveFiles.


If sFolder <> "" Then
    Set FOLDER = FSO.getfolder(sFolder)
    Set files = FOLDER.files
    For Each file In files
        'ONLY WORK WITH EXCEL FILES
        If file.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=file.path
```

Comment: Unrelated note: You do realize that "Dim FOLDER, files, file, FSO As Object" will declare FOLDER, files and file as Variant, and only FSO as an Object, right?

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted?

Answer (score 1):

xlsx is a "macro-free" workbook.  To use VBA in the new file format, the file must be saved as an xlsm file.

EDIT: I read the question too hastily.  If you want to identify excel files from the FSO object, use `file.Type LIKE "Microsoft Excel *"` or similar.  Or, check the file's extension against ".xls*"

EDIT

The whole concept of identifying the file type by looking at the file name is fundamentally flawed.  It's too easily broken by changes to file extensions and/or the "type" texts associated with those descriptions.  It's easily broken by, say, an image file named "file.xls".  I would just try opening the file with Workbooks.Open and catch the error.  I'd probably put this logic in a separate function:

```
Function OpenWorkbook(strPath As String) As Workbook

    On Error GoTo ErrorLabel

    Set OpenWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

ExitLabel:
    Exit Function

ErrorLabel:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Resume ExitLabel
    Else
        'other error handling code here
        Resume ExitLabel
    End If
End Function
```

Then you can consume the function like this:

```
Dim w As Workbook
Set w = OpenWorkbook(file.Path)
If Not (w Is Nothing) Then
    '...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having has to do with this line:

```
If file.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then
```

Try adding and replacing it with this:

```
// add these lines just AFTER the line 'For Each file In files'
IsXLFile = False

FilePath = file.path
FilePath2 = Right(FilePath, 5)
FilePath3 = Mid(FilePath2, InStr(1, FilePath2, ".") + 1)

If UCase(Left(FilePath3, 2)) = "XL" Then IsXLFile = True

// replace faulty line with this line
If IsXLFile = True Then
```

Let me know how it works. Yes, it'd be possible to compress the statements that start with FilePath into one expression but I left it like that for clarity. Vote and accept the answer if good and follow-up if not.

Have a nice day.

Comment: FilesystemObject has a GetExtensionName property - you can use that to get the extension directly.

Comment: True but the poster mentioned that the code is from 2003, 8 years old. And it blew up because MS added some file extensions. Who knows what changes to the file system might come along till 2019. But Right and Mid should still be there and Microsoft will probably not change the first 2 letters (XL) of their product name. I'm not saying this is the most optimized code but I'll say that it'll work for a long time.

Comment: This makes assumptions about the file name.  Suppose my workbook is called "some data.2.xls"?

Comment: @Frenchie - the code was from Excel 2003, not the year 2003.  It was only a suggestion, since the OP is already using the FSO...

Comment: @phoog: then it'll still work because I'm looking at the expression that's after the last dot since I'm taking 5 characters (.xls or .xlsm) and in the case of .2.xls the extension would be parsed as "2.xls" inFilePath2 and then "xls" in FilePath3.

Comment: @TimWilliams: yes, there is more than one way of doing it. And yes, it's XL 2003 and the code could be younger, but my guess is not by much.

Comment: @frenchie when I wrote that comment, you were taking the last six characters.  But what if they come up with a new extension like ".xlsgrfm"?

Comment: @phoog: yes, I updated to 5. If they come up with .xlsiwfowh then it's their problem:) But my guess is they won't.